# Mapping a Set of Enum - Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, enums, set

What is missing or wrong?

I'm trying to map the class below, which has an Enum Set. I did exactly as it is in the documentation, in other topics or sites. But it did not work.

When creating a new object, only the other attributes are saved. The Set is ignored.

P.S.: it works fine for reading.

I'm using spring-boot, mysql, hibernate.

Enum:

```
public enum Role {
    ROLE_A,
    ROLE_B,
    ROLE_N;
}
```

Class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Users")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50, unique = true)
    @NaturalId
    private String username;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String password;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean active = true;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100)
    private String lastname;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 100, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_user"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

// constructor
// gets & setters
// hashCode & equals
// toString
}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
  id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  active BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
  name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  lastname VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  UNIQUE INDEX unique_username(username),
  UNIQUE INDEX unique_email(email)
);

CREATE TABLE Roles (
  id_user BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  role VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id_user, role),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_user)
    REFERENCES Users(id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

TEST:

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("nikolas");
u.setLastname("Martins");
u.setEmail("nik@outlook.com");
u.setUsername("nik");
u.setPassword("password");
u.getRoles().add(Role.ROLE_A);
u.getRoles().add(Role.ROLE_B);
entityManager.save(u);
```

Comment: everything seems perfect. Can you re-check whether the roles set actually has something just before you call entitymanager.persist(user)? May be something is amiss.

Comment: I've edited my question and included the code I'm using to test.

Comment: I wonder if is something related to ID and auto_increment clause on DDL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by changing the way I work with Hibernate.

I was using EntityManagerFactory or SessionFactory to get a Session and perform the operations, however as I'm using the Spring Boot I followed this 'How To' guide and, surprise, it worked: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

In summary, I stopped using Session, stopped implementing DAOs, and let Spring handle it for me.